# how come i can't populate textarea with <br>, by the way im using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is the ajax im using,

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../../Ajax/<?php echo $exercise_num ?>",
data: "user_input=" + user_input,
success: function(resp){
//output
 $("#message").text(resp);
}
});
}
```

and when i try to populate `$("#message").text(resp)` with

```
public function pb3()
{
$num1 = 10;
$num2 = 7;
echo "$num1 + $num2 = "; echo $num1 + $num2;echo "<br>hi";
}
```

my html code:
`Message: <font id="message"></font>`

the output: 
`Message: 10 + 7 = 17<br> hi;`

or is there any way to use br in the textarea of font?

Comment: @ 3 first answers
the <br> disappears but wont do newline

here's the output
    Message: 10 + 7 = 17 hi

Answer (score 2):

You can't have html inside a textarea.  It won't be interpreted properly, and it should be escaped to prevent injection.  You want to use a newline:

```
echo "\n\nhi";
```

Comment: the <br> disappears but didnt do newline here's the output Message: 10 + 7 = 17 hi

Comment: @MarkJeffreyCalvarioLopez You may need to use two newlines

Comment: same output: Message: 10 + 7 = 17 hi

disregard:
123456789

Comment: @MarkJeffreyCalvarioLopez idk what to tell you; I don't have a problem

Comment: i found out something
ff,chrome browser dont show that it does newline

but when i "inspect element" it shows. what do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`$("#message").text(resp.replace("<br>", "\n"));`

ref : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `<br>` with `\n` , 
main thing is you cannot put html tags on textarea value

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../../Ajax/<?php echo $exercise_num ?>",
data: "user_input=" + user_input,
success: function(resp){
//output
    $("#message").text(resp.split("<br>").join("\n"));
}
});
}
```